# Endless prompt for credentials on a web application with host header

Tags: 2010, host-header

I want to create a web application tied to a domain name within my server. Following are the steps I followed:

- Modified the server host file for `www.xyz.com` to resolve to localhost
- I am able to ping `www.xyz.com` which does resolve to localhost
- Create a web application with host header `www.xyz.com`
- Created a site collection

But I can't login to that site for reason. When I visit `http://www.xyz.com` through the browser, I get prompted for credentials but it doesn't accept my credentials even though I assigned myself as the site collection admin. Did I miss a step above? With 2007, I followed the same steps and it works.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you now running on Windows Server 2008 or 2008 R2? In Windows Server 2008 they implemented a security check called the "Loopback Check" to restrict doing just what you are trying to do :)

Check out the following KB article for a registry work-around. This will only happen when you try to browse to the host header from the server that hosts the site. If you browse to the site from another computer, this should not be a problem.

If you are on a non-production server, the easiest option is the #2, add "DisableLoopbackCheck" to the appropriate registry key.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Comment: It would be also usefull to just try accessing the site from another PC.

Comment: It is also possible it is an Kerberos issue, but only if Kerberos is the selected auth schema.

Comment: The loopback check was introduced in windows server 2003 (a service pack), although it does ship with 2008.

Comment: Yes it is windows 2008 R2.

Comment: So I was able to access the site externally without changing anything on the server in question. I guess I will have to enable the DisableLoopbackCheck to be able to access the site internally from the server. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A follow up question. Currently, the search is failing to crawl the server because it can't login. I guess I need to turn on DisableLoopbackCheck for that to work. How would you handle this situation in production environment?

Comment: The linked KB article gives you both answers. For non-production, Method #2 is easiest "DisableLoopbackCheck". For production servers, use Method #1 and the BackConnectionHostNames option with the specific host headers to allow. Method #1 is more secure.