# Always prompted for authentication in Alternate Access Mapping and cannot log in

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

I just added an alternate access mapping entry to one of my web applications and upon trying to access it in the browser I am prompted for authentication over and over again without ever being permitted in.  Even entering the site url as a trusted intranet site in IE the prompts do not cease.

Comment: Related? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13308/endless-prompt-for-credentials-on-a-web-application-with-host-header

Comment: I don't think so because LoopBackCheck disabling is for accessing sites from the server which is hosting the site.  I get this no matter what machine I am using to access the site.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's the problem with DisableLoopBack. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861/en-us

Comment: Voted up to 0 from -1 as it is a good and valid answer, although it may not have been the solution for this particular user.

Answer (score 1):

An IISReset on the web server cleared it up but I am not sure why it took that to fix it.